# MobileDevice Framework AMDeviceCopyValue get ECID

Tags: ios, c, mobiledevice.framework

(Hope this post don't get too messy)
Hello, I have a question about the AMDeviceCopyValue function in mobiledevice library, because I want to grab the ECID from a connected iDevice and print it, in the c console.

```
    #include "MobileDevice.h"

void device_callback(struct am_device_notification_callback_info *info, void *arg) {
    struct am_device *dev;
    if (info->msg == ADNCI_MSG_CONNECTED) {
        dev = info->dev;
        CFRetain(dev);
        AMDSetLogLevel(5);
        AMDeviceConnect(dev);
        assert(AMDeviceIsPaired(dev));
        assert(!AMDeviceValidatePairing(dev));
        assert(!AMDeviceStartSession(dev));

        assert(AMDeviceIsPaired(dev));
        assert(AMDeviceValidatePairing(dev) == 0);

        CFStringRef Serial = AMDeviceCopyValue(dev, 0, CFSTR("SerialNumber"));
        printf("Serial  (%s)", CFStringGetCStringPtr(Serial, CFStringGetSystemEncoding()));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct am_device_notification *notify;
    AMDeviceNotificationSubscribe(&device_callback, 0, 0, NULL, &notify);
    CFRunLoopRun();

}
```

This code will print out the serial number of the iDevice,but I want it to print out the ECID so I read at theiphonewiki that if I wanted to get the ECID I had to use the value "UniqueChipID" with the function (AMDeviceCopyValue) [link](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/ECID)

but that doesn't seem to work very well....

Cause if I edit the value from SerialNumber to UniqueChipID, and run the code it all crashes.... :(

so if you want to try to help me, first you have to create a header file(I called it MobileDevice.h) (you also have to add MobileDevice.framework (its a private apple framework found in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks )  and add this code to the MobileDevice.h

```
    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   MobileDevice.h - interface to MobileDevice.framework 
 *   $LastChangedDate: 2007-07-09 18:59:29 -0700 (Mon, 09 Jul 2007) $
 *
 * Copied from http://iphonesvn.halifrag.com/svn/iPhone/
 * With modifications from Allen Porter and Scott Turner
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#ifndef MOBILEDEVICE_H
#define MOBILEDEVICE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if defined(WIN32)
#include <CoreFoundation.h>
typedef unsigned int mach_error_t;
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <mach/error.h>
#endif  

/* Error codes */
#define MDERR_APPLE_MOBILE  (err_system(0x3a))
#define MDERR_IPHONE        (err_sub(0))

/* Apple Mobile (AM*) errors */
#define MDERR_OK                ERR_SUCCESS
#define MDERR_SYSCALL           (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x01)
#define MDERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY     (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x03)
#define MDERR_QUERY_FAILED      (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x04) 
#define MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x0b)
#define MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x25)

/* Apple File Connection (AFC*) errors */
#define MDERR_AFC_OUT_OF_MEMORY 0x03

/* USBMux errors */
#define MDERR_USBMUX_ARG_NULL   0x16
#define MDERR_USBMUX_FAILED     0xffffffff

/* Messages passed to device notification callbacks: passed as part of
 * am_device_notification_callback_info. */
#define ADNCI_MSG_CONNECTED     1
#define ADNCI_MSG_DISCONNECTED  2
#define ADNCI_MSG_UNKNOWN       3

#define AMD_IPHONE_PRODUCT_ID   0x1290
#define AMD_IPHONE_SERIAL       "3391002d9c804d105e2c8c7d94fc35b6f3d214a3"

/* Services, found in /System/Library/Lockdown/Services.plist */
#define AMSVC_AFC                   CFSTR("com.apple.afc")
#define AMSVC_BACKUP                CFSTR("com.apple.mobilebackup")
#define AMSVC_CRASH_REPORT_COPY     CFSTR("com.apple.crashreportcopy")
#define AMSVC_DEBUG_IMAGE_MOUNT     CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.debug_image_mount")
#define AMSVC_NOTIFICATION_PROXY    CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy")
#define AMSVC_PURPLE_TEST           CFSTR("com.apple.purpletestr")
#define AMSVC_SOFTWARE_UPDATE       CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.software_update")
#define AMSVC_SYNC                  CFSTR("com.apple.mobilesync")
#define AMSVC_SCREENSHOT            CFSTR("com.apple.screenshotr")
#define AMSVC_SYSLOG_RELAY          CFSTR("com.apple.syslog_relay")
#define AMSVC_SYSTEM_PROFILER       CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.system_profiler")

typedef unsigned int afc_error_t;
typedef unsigned int usbmux_error_t;
typedef unsigned int service_conn_t;

struct am_recovery_device;

typedef struct am_device_notification_callback_info {
    struct am_device *dev;  /* 0    device */ 
    unsigned int msg;       /* 4    one of ADNCI_MSG_* */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device_notification_callback_info;

/* The type of the device restore notification callback functions.
 * TODO: change to correct type. */
typedef void (*am_restore_device_notification_callback)(struct
    am_recovery_device *);

/* This is a CoreFoundation object of class AMRecoveryModeDevice. */
typedef struct am_recovery_device {
    unsigned char unknown0[8];                          /* 0 */
    am_restore_device_notification_callback callback;   /* 8 */
    void *user_info;                                    /* 12 */
    unsigned char unknown1[12];                         /* 16 */
    unsigned int readwrite_pipe;                        /* 28 */
    unsigned char read_pipe;                            /* 32 */
    unsigned char write_ctrl_pipe;                      /* 33 */
    unsigned char read_unknown_pipe;                    /* 34 */
    unsigned char write_file_pipe;                      /* 35 */
    unsigned char write_input_pipe;                     /* 36 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_recovery_device;

/* A CoreFoundation object of class AMRestoreModeDevice. */
typedef struct am_restore_device {
    unsigned char unknown[32];
    int port;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_restore_device;

/* The type of the device notification callback function. */
typedef void(*am_device_notification_callback)(struct
    am_device_notification_callback_info *, void* arg);

/* The type of the _AMDDeviceAttached function.
 * TODO: change to correct type. */
typedef void *amd_device_attached_callback;


typedef struct am_device {
    unsigned char unknown0[16]; /* 0 - zero */
    unsigned int device_id;     /* 16 */
    unsigned int product_id;    /* 20 - set to AMD_IPHONE_PRODUCT_ID */
    char *serial;               /* 24 - set to AMD_IPHONE_SERIAL */
    unsigned int unknown1;      /* 28 */
    unsigned char unknown2[4];  /* 32 */
    unsigned int lockdown_conn; /* 36 */
    unsigned char unknown3[8];  /* 40 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device;

typedef struct am_device_notification {
    unsigned int unknown0;                      /* 0 */
    unsigned int unknown1;                      /* 4 */
    unsigned int unknown2;                      /* 8 */
    am_device_notification_callback callback;   /* 12 */ 
    unsigned int unknown3;                      /* 16 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device_notification;

typedef struct afc_connection {
    unsigned int handle;            /* 0 */
    unsigned int unknown0;          /* 4 */
    unsigned char unknown1;         /* 8 */
    unsigned char padding[3];       /* 9 */
    unsigned int unknown2;          /* 12 */
    unsigned int unknown3;          /* 16 */
    unsigned int unknown4;          /* 20 */
    unsigned int fs_block_size;     /* 24 */
    unsigned int sock_block_size;   /* 28: always 0x3c */
    unsigned int io_timeout;        /* 32: from AFCConnectionOpen, usu. 0 */
    void *afc_lock;                 /* 36 */
    unsigned int context;           /* 40 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_connection;

typedef struct afc_directory {
    unsigned char unknown[0];   /* size unknown */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_directory;

typedef struct afc_dictionary {
    unsigned char unknown[0];   /* size unknown */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_dictionary;

typedef unsigned long long afc_file_ref;

typedef struct usbmux_listener_1 {                  /* offset   value in iTunes */
    unsigned int unknown0;                  /* 0        1 */
    unsigned char *unknown1;                /* 4        ptr, maybe device? */
    amd_device_attached_callback callback;  /* 8        _AMDDeviceAttached */
    unsigned int unknown3;                  /* 12 */
    unsigned int unknown4;                  /* 16 */
    unsigned int unknown5;                  /* 20 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) usbmux_listener_1;

typedef struct usbmux_listener_2 {
    unsigned char unknown0[4144];
} __attribute__ ((packed)) usbmux_listener_2;

typedef struct am_bootloader_control_packet {
    unsigned char opcode;       /* 0 */
    unsigned char length;       /* 1 */
    unsigned char magic[2];     /* 2: 0x34, 0x12 */
    unsigned char payload[0];   /* 4 */
} __attribute__ ((packed)) am_bootloader_control_packet;

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Public routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

void AMDSetLogLevel(int level);

/*  Registers a notification with the current run loop. The callback gets
 *  copied into the notification struct, as well as being registered with the
 *  current run loop. dn_unknown3 gets copied into unknown3 in the same.
 *  (Maybe dn_unknown3 is a user info parameter that gets passed as an arg to
 *  the callback?) unused0 and unused1 are both 0 when iTunes calls this.
 *  In iTunes the callback is located from $3db78e-$3dbbaf.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK            if successful
 *      MDERR_SYSCALL       if CFRunLoopAddSource() failed
 *      MDERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY if we ran out of memory
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceNotificationSubscribe(am_device_notification_callback
    callback, unsigned int unused0, unsigned int unused1, void* //unsigned int
    dn_unknown3, struct am_device_notification **notification);

/*  Connects to the iPhone. Pass in the am_device structure that the
 *  notification callback will give to you.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successfully connected
 *      MDERR_SYSCALL           if setsockopt() failed
 *      MDERR_QUERY_FAILED      if the daemon query failed
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if USBMuxConnectByPort returned 0xffffffff
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceConnect(struct am_device *device);

/*  Calls PairingRecordPath() on the given device, than tests whether the path
 *  which that function returns exists. During the initial connect, the path
 *  returned by that function is '/', and so this returns 1.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      0   if the path did not exist
 *      1   if it did
 */

int AMDeviceIsPaired(struct am_device *device);

/*  iTunes calls this function immediately after testing whether the device is
 *  paired. It creates a pairing file and establishes a Lockdown connection.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the supplied device is null
 *      MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   if the load_dict() call failed
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceValidatePairing(struct am_device *device);

/*  Creates a Lockdown session and adjusts the device structure appropriately
 *  to indicate that the session has been started. iTunes calls this function
 *  after validating pairing.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
 *      MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   if the load_dict() call failed
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceStartSession(struct am_device *device);

/* Starts a service and returns a handle that can be used in order to further
 * access the service. You should stop the session and disconnect before using
 * the service. iTunes calls this function after starting a session. It starts 
 * the service and the SSL connection. unknown may safely be
 * NULL (it is when iTunes calls this), but if it is not, then it will be
 * filled upon function exit. service_name should be one of the AMSVC_*
 * constants. If the service is AFC (AMSVC_AFC), then the handle is the handle
 * that will be used for further AFC* calls.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_SYSCALL           if the setsockopt() call failed
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceStartService(struct am_device *device, CFStringRef 
    service_name, service_conn_t *handle, unsigned int *
    unknown);

mach_error_t AMDeviceStartHouseArrestService(struct am_device *device, CFStringRef identifier, void *unknown, service_conn_t *handle, unsigned int *what);

/* Stops a session. You should do this before accessing services.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
 */

mach_error_t AMDeviceStopSession(struct am_device *device);

/* Opens an Apple File Connection. You must start the appropriate service
 * first with AMDeviceStartService(). In iTunes, io_timeout is 0.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 *      MDERR_AFC_OUT_OF_MEMORY if malloc() failed
 */

afc_error_t AFCConnectionOpen(service_conn_t handle, unsigned int io_timeout,
    struct afc_connection **conn);

/* Pass in a pointer to an afc_device_info structure. It will be filled. */
afc_error_t AFCDeviceInfoOpen(afc_connection *conn, struct
    afc_dictionary **info);

/* Turns debug mode on if the environment variable AFCDEBUG is set to a numeric
 * value, or if the file '/AFCDEBUG' is present and contains a value. */
void AFCPlatformInit();

/* Opens a directory on the iPhone. Pass in a pointer in dir to be filled in.
 * Note that this normally only accesses the iTunes sandbox/partition as the
 * root, which is /var/root/Media. Pathnames are specified with '/' delimiters
 * as in Unix style.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful
 */

afc_error_t AFCDirectoryOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path,
                             struct afc_directory **dir);

/* Acquires the next entry in a directory previously opened with
 * AFCDirectoryOpen(). When dirent is filled with a NULL value, then the end
 * of the directory has been reached. '.' and '..' will be returned as the
 * first two entries in each directory except the root; you may want to skip
 * over them.
 *
 * Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if successful, even if no entries remain
 */

afc_error_t AFCDirectoryRead(afc_connection *conn/*unsigned int unused*/, struct afc_directory *dir,
    char **dirent);

afc_error_t AFCDirectoryClose(afc_connection *conn, struct afc_directory *dir);
afc_error_t AFCDirectoryCreate(afc_connection *conn, const char *dirname);
afc_error_t AFCRemovePath(afc_connection *conn, const char *dirname);
afc_error_t AFCRenamePath(afc_connection *conn, const char *from, const char *to);
afc_error_t AFCLinkPath(afc_connection *conn, long long int linktype, const char *target, const char *linkname);

/* Returns the context field of the given AFC connection. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetContext(afc_connection *conn);

/* Returns the fs_block_size field of the given AFC connection. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetFSBlockSize(afc_connection *conn);

/* Returns the io_timeout field of the given AFC connection. In iTunes this is
 * 0. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetIOTimeout(afc_connection *conn);

/* Returns the sock_block_size field of the given AFC connection. */
unsigned int AFCConnectionGetSocketBlockSize(afc_connection *conn);

/* Closes the given AFC connection. */
afc_error_t AFCConnectionClose(afc_connection *conn);

/* Registers for device notifications related to the restore process. unknown0
 * is zero when iTunes calls this. In iTunes,
 * the callbacks are located at:
 *      1: $3ac68e-$3ac6b1, calls $3ac542(unknown1, arg, 0)
 *      2: $3ac66a-$3ac68d, calls $3ac542(unknown1, 0, arg)
 *      3: $3ac762-$3ac785, calls $3ac6b2(unknown1, arg, 0)
 *      4: $3ac73e-$3ac761, calls $3ac6b2(unknown1, 0, arg)
 */

unsigned int AMRestoreRegisterForDeviceNotifications(
    am_restore_device_notification_callback dfu_connect_callback,
    am_restore_device_notification_callback recovery_connect_callback,
    am_restore_device_notification_callback dfu_disconnect_callback,
    am_restore_device_notification_callback recovery_disconnect_callback,
    unsigned int unknown0,
    void *user_info);

/* Causes the restore functions to spit out (unhelpful) progress messages to
 * the file specified by the given path. iTunes always calls this right before
 * restoring with a path of
 * "$HOME/Library/Logs/iPhone Updater Logs/iPhoneUpdater X.log", where X is an
 * unused number.
 */

unsigned int AMRestoreEnableFileLogging(char *path);

/* Initializes a new option dictionary to default values. Pass the constant
 * kCFAllocatorDefault as the allocator. The option dictionary looks as
 * follows:
 * {
 *      NORImageType => 'production',
 *      AutoBootDelay => 0,
 *      KernelCacheType => 'Release',
 *      UpdateBaseband => true,
 *      DFUFileType => 'RELEASE',
 *      SystemImageType => 'User',
 *      CreateFilesystemPartitions => true,
 *      FlashNOR => true,
 *      RestoreBootArgs => 'rd=md0 nand-enable-reformat=1 -progress'
 *      BootImageType => 'User'
 *  }
 *
 * Returns:
 *      the option dictionary   if successful
 *      NULL                    if out of memory
 */ 

CFMutableDictionaryRef AMRestoreCreateDefaultOptions(CFAllocatorRef allocator);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Less-documented public routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* mode 2 = read, mode 3 = write */
afc_error_t AFCFileRefOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path,
    unsigned long long mode, afc_file_ref *ref);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefSeek(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    unsigned long long offset1, unsigned long long offset2);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefRead(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    void *buf, unsigned int *len);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefSetFileSize(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    unsigned long long offset);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefWrite(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
    const void *buf, unsigned int len);
afc_error_t AFCFileRefClose(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref);

afc_error_t AFCFileInfoOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path, struct
    afc_dictionary **info);
afc_error_t AFCKeyValueRead(struct afc_dictionary *dict, char **key, char **
    val);
afc_error_t AFCKeyValueClose(struct afc_dictionary *dict);

unsigned int AMRestorePerformRecoveryModeRestore(struct am_recovery_device *
    rdev, CFDictionaryRef opts, void *callback, void *user_info);
unsigned int AMRestorePerformRestoreModeRestore(struct am_restore_device *
    rdev, CFDictionaryRef opts, void *callback, void *user_info);

struct am_restore_device *AMRestoreModeDeviceCreate(unsigned int unknown0,
    unsigned int connection_id, unsigned int unknown1);

unsigned int AMRestoreCreatePathsForBundle(CFStringRef restore_bundle_path,
    CFStringRef kernel_cache_type, CFStringRef boot_image_type, unsigned int
    unknown0, CFStringRef *firmware_dir_path, CFStringRef *
    kernelcache_restore_path, unsigned int unknown1, CFStringRef *
    ramdisk_path);

unsigned int AMDeviceGetConnectionID(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceEnterRecovery(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceDisconnect(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceRetain(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceRelease(struct am_device *device);
CFStringRef AMDeviceCopyValue(struct am_device *device, unsigned int, CFStringRef cfstring);
CFStringRef AMDeviceCopyDeviceIdentifier(struct am_device *device);

typedef void (*notify_callback)(CFStringRef notification, void *data);

mach_error_t AMDPostNotification(service_conn_t socket, CFStringRef  notification, CFStringRef userinfo);
mach_error_t AMDObserveNotification(void *socket, CFStringRef notification);
mach_error_t AMDListenForNotifications(void *socket, notify_callback cb, void *data);
mach_error_t AMDShutdownNotificationProxy(void *socket);

/*edits by geohot*/
mach_error_t AMDeviceDeactivate(struct am_device *device);
mach_error_t AMDeviceActivate(struct am_device *device, CFMutableDictionaryRef);
/*end*/

void *AMDeviceSerialize(struct am_device *device);
void AMDAddLogFileDescriptor(int fd);
//kern_return_t AMDeviceSendMessage(service_conn_t socket, void *unused, CFPropertyListRef plist);
//kern_return_t AMDeviceReceiveMessage(service_conn_t socket, CFDictionaryRef options, CFPropertyListRef * result);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Semi-private routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/*  Pass in a usbmux_listener_1 structure and a usbmux_listener_2 structure
 *  pointer, which will be filled with the resulting usbmux_listener_2.
 *
 *  Returns:
 *      MDERR_OK                if completed successfully
 *      MDERR_USBMUX_ARG_NULL   if one of the arguments was NULL
 *      MDERR_USBMUX_FAILED     if the listener was not created successfully
 */

usbmux_error_t USBMuxListenerCreate(struct usbmux_listener_1 *esi_fp8, struct
    usbmux_listener_2 **eax_fp12);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Less-documented semi-private routines
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

usbmux_error_t USBMuxListenerHandleData(void *);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   Private routines - here be dragons
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* AMRestorePerformRestoreModeRestore() calls this function with a dictionary
 * in order to perform certain special restore operations
 * (RESTORED_OPERATION_*). It is thought that this function might enable
 * significant access to the phone. */

typedef unsigned int (*t_performOperation)(struct am_restore_device *rdev,
    CFDictionaryRef op); // __attribute__ ((regparm(2)));

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Would loved any help I can get!!!
And I hope this post is´nt to messy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value associated with UniqueChipID is a CFNumber not a CFString.

```
4 : <CFString 0x7fa18bf62f90 [0x7fff7279ecf0]>{contents = "UniqueChipID"} = <CFNumber 0x18a19201535c55c5 [0x7fff7279ecf0]>{value = +0000000000000000, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
```

Incidentally, CFShow is your friend.
Example:

```
 CFNumberRef ecid = AMDeviceCopyValue(dev, 0, CFSTR("UniqueChipID"));
```

Comment: CFNumber is not a variable :( ?  Maybe I misunderstood what you where trying to say,  so if you maybe could give me the code you used to get a result I would be really happy :D

Comment: See updated answer. Make sure you accept the answer when it works for you. I use the code above and it works just fine.

Comment: Last question, how do I then print out the ecid?

Comment: Uh. You can start by trying NSLog(@"ecid is %@", ecid);

Comment: If you have more questions, ask another question. I've answered your question please accept the answer. Thanks.