# C how to print CFNumberRef

Tags: ios, c, mobiledevice.framework

Quick question im wondering how I could print CFNumberRef.
Im currently working on a program that comunicate with mobiledevice framework (Apple) that will print the ecid of a iDevice. And I currently have one problem, I read here [link](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/ECID) 
that to get the ECID you have "Call the AMDeviceCopyValue function in the MobileDevice Framework " and after some help here earlier ( [link to last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220430/)
) now I have one last question, on theiphonewiki it say that "It returns the ECID as a CFNumber(kCFNumberSInt64Type) object. ", and the question I now have is how to a print to the console CFNumber(kCFNumberSInt64Type) object??? (im working in c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CFShow()` to print core foundation types to the console.

```
CFShow(yourCFNumberInstance);
```

You can also use `NSLog()` if you want to format things:

```
NSLog(CFSTR("Number is %@"), yourCFNumberInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks :D (just started to learn C so it´s  nice that so many people will help me  :D )